# Как правильно подвинуть flex-элементы, не теряя отцентровку?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Здравствуйте. Как подвинуть flex-элементы `title_text_1` и `text_1` так, чтобы первый(title_text_1), при масштабировании, был всегда по центру общей ширины страницы, а второй(text_1) был чуть-чуть отодвинут от левой стороны, как на схеме по картинке. Главное условие, чтобы при изменении масштаба они в таком положении, не съезжая. Спасибо.
Ссылка для визуального примера: [shveypokrov.ru](http://shveypokrov.ru)
PS. Ипользовал margin, но при масштабировании всё становится не по центру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
section {
  background: url(img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border: 20px solid black;  
  border-top: 0px solid black;
  border-left: 20px solid black;
  border-right: 20px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 627px;
}
.Nashi_Tseny {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.text_1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 3px solid gold;
}
.text_1 p {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 7%;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
     <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
      <div class="title_text_1">
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="text_1">
       <p>Облачения:<p>
       <p>-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от                       <strong><span                                               class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong>                       рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
       <p>-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от                   <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>                 </strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
       <p>Подрясники:</p>
       <p>Подризники:</p>
       <p>Рясы:</p>
       <p>Стихари:</p>
       <p>Скуфии:от 800 рублей;</p>
       <p>Камилавки:от 1700</p>
       <p>Крещальные:</p>
       <p>Облачения для храма:</p>
       <p>Вышитые кресты:</p>
       <p>Кадильный уголь:</p>

       <p>*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами                  шьются по заказу</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что за 90% на картинке? о чем это?

Comment: Масштаб) При масштабировании смещается, несмотря на margin

Comment: И еще у тебя вот тут вот <p>Облачения:<p> , закрывающий <p> не закрыт...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

контейнеру Nashi_Tseny задал

```
display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
```

Ну и

```
   .text_1 {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 3px solid gold;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```css
section {
  background: url(img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border: 20px solid black;
  border-top: 0px solid black;
  border-left: 20px solid black;
  border-right: 20px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 627px;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.text_1 {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 3px solid gold;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.text_1 p {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 7%;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
    <div class="title_text_1">
      <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="text_1">
      <p>Облачения:
        <p>
          <p>-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span                                               class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
          <p>-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>                 </strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
          <p>Подрясники:</p>
          <p>Подризники:</p>
          <p>Рясы:</p>
          <p>Стихари:</p>
          <p>Скуфии:от 800 рублей;</p>
          <p>Камилавки:от 1700</p>
          <p>Крещальные:</p>
          <p>Облачения для храма:</p>
          <p>Вышитые кресты:</p>
          <p>Кадильный уголь:</p>

          <p>*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А для title_tex_1?, Он при масштабировнии смещается

Comment: Вот так попробуй, должно быть так, как хочешь

Comment: получилось вот что: https://ibb.co/mJFzQ6

Comment: Извини, в самом примере все правильно, а выше что отдельно перепутал column с  row... ты видать от туда скопировал)))

Comment: И еще, не забывай, что при медиа будешь менять значения под разные мониторы...  Ты не старайся все делать в одном , а будет везде одинаково...  Не забывай про @media

Comment: Т.е. менять в своём коде те первых два отрывка, которые Вы дали первыми, а то, что в сниппете не трогать?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69054/discussion-between-quick-brown-fox-and-air).

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
вот сюда надо вставить css как обычно ты пишешь код
}

Comment: а это мета тег  который масштабирует под телефоны и планшеты <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">